# Stay in sync with a public git and sync to a private git with modifications

Tags: git, repository

I am trying some variations on an open source project and want to keep in sync with the master git.
On the other hand, I am sharing with an other developer a git repository with modified sources until we have a set of working diffs to submit to the master project.
We want to have a shared repository to track each other's work, since we do not work in the same location.
I set up a git with two remotes and my tree is ahead of master of a few commits. This is no surprise.

```
git pull origin
```

works with no problem.
When I try to sync to the private shared repository, I try a

```
git push my_own_shared_git
```

I get this error

```
! [rejected]        HEAD -> master (non-fast forward)
```

I am sure that git can handle this and much worse situations, but I would like to know how to handle it in the most natural and sensible way.
Ideally, I would like to handle a branch of the `HEAD` on `origin` and keep local history and diffs until I am able to submit my patches.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error indicates that your mjy_own_shared_git has some commits which you have not.
So just type

```
git pull my_own_shared_git
```

before

```
git push my_own_shared_git
```